# Pylons: free module-level variables?

Tags: python, object, scope, singleton, pylons

Not even sure if module-level is correct here, but...

I have a Pylons project and within the model component I have a global variable, doc, in `__init__.py` that I want to use from different Query objects. (doc is a Document handle on an XML file that I am using as a fake DB.) My question is, when does `__init__.py`'s scope end? Currently I am not freeing the Document with doc.unlink() and I am not sure where to put that.

The alternative design I was thinking about deals with making the consuming object (Query) have a class-level variable of this doc (i.e. make it a singleton). But it appears that the life of my Query object is such that doc always gets reallocated a new Document handle.

```
class Query(object):
    doc = None 

    def __init__(self, content=None):
        self.content = content
        if self.doc == None:                        
            self.doc = parse(os.path.join(config['app_conf']['xmldb'], "sample_search_result.xml"))
```

I can tell because the address of the elements within the Document keep changing.

Anyone want to help a noobie out?

Answer (score 0):

Objects only stop existing when 1) no references to them exist, or 2) the interpreter ends. A module/package keeps a reference to all module-level names in its private dict; deleting all references to the module in all other modules as well as in sys.modules, *and* all references to any objects within it will release the module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the **doc** object in `globals`? Since it's an immutable object it shall be the perfect place to store it. Than you can reference `globals` from any controller and pass it to a `Query` object (during `__init__` or explicitly when calling a method on the object)

You can also try to store the **doc** object in the controller's `session` (if per session reads required)